Confusion in power delivered into the grid
I have been working on grid tied inverters but am confused about the working of the current injected into the grid.
I have implemented the phase locked loop using the notch filter according to the application note as shown and now I have a same phased wave and want to inject power into the grid.


I have seen that if the phase angle of the inverter circuit is greater that of the grid then the current can be injected. Also if the amplitude of one wave is greater than the other,power can be injected if I am not wrong. But I am confused about the real and reactive power injected. I am not know about the nature of the grid so is it necessary to consider that???
Secondly if I am injecting power into the grid shall I work on only changing the amplitude of the voltage or phase should be changed also???
If phase is changed then what is the need for a PLL to have the phases locked??

kindly explain these power injections to me as I am new into this and have a slight connfusion wheather to control peak voltage or phase, and which should be prefered.

If your inverter is simply to inject power into the grid, then it needs to be programmed to inject a current that is proportional to the instantaneous voltage, the voltage indicated by the PLL that is filtering the grid voltage. Control the constant of proportionality to control the amount of power injected.
It's effectively synthesising a negative resistance (compare with a positive resistance that draws a current proportional to the voltage). The current will obviously be in phase with the grid voltage. The voltage it's injected at, so determining the instantaneous power, will be whatever the grid voltage is at that moment.
If OTOH this inverter is to be used for power factor correction, then the current will be injected at a phase offset from the voltage waveform. The command for how much power, and what phase angle to use, would come from another system. There's no reason it needs to be limited to injecting a sinewave current. If you are required to power factor correct a rectifier/capacitor load, then you would only need bursts of injected current for a short time leading up to the voltage peaks.

the current will be inphase with the grid or the voltage..I am confused about these things. My purpose is to give current into  the grid no need to  adjuust power factor.

@kam1212 no problem then, just synthesise a negative resistor by injecting an instantaneous current proportional to the instantaneous PLL-filtered voltage.

Power factor need not have a phase angle - eg harmonic loads,

@Neil_UK is my PLL method correct or I should use the dq frame method for controlling the current and voltage.

@kam1212 I'm disturbed that you use the phrase 'controlling the current and voltage', is it merely sloppy, or does it indicate a deep misunderstanding? You cannot control voltage and current, pick one. With a grid-tie, the grid determines the voltage, you just inject current into whatever voltage you are presented with. dq frame is not applicable here, it's not even wrong.

@Neil_UK actually my initial understanding was that I would simply have the two voltages in phase and have the voltage of the PLL generated abit higher than the grid voltage and inject current into it. But then I found some power angle formula P=V1V2Sin(delta)/X. This was for real power injectected and I donot know If i really do have to care if the current is real or reactive interms of the grid. This equation states that if the delta is zero than no power is injected in the grid. Can you please explain it.

@kam1212 what 'two voltages'??? There's the grid voltage, and the current you inject into it. One voltage, one current. The first you don't control, the second you do control. Have you heard of the control mode for an inverter to make it output a controlled current into an arbitrary voltage? That is what a grid-tie inverter uses. Adjust your synthesised 'negative resistance' by changing the constant of proportionality between the grid voltage you measure, and the current output you create, to control the power going into the grid. One Iout = parameter*Vgrid equation, no phases to worry about.

@Neil_UK the voltage I make out from my inverter is the second voltage.

@Neil_UK can you check this tutorial out. This is what I mean and am having confusion with. Thanks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8WZn6YYoxw

@kam1212 parts are correct, parts are irrelevant, and parts are wrong. In practice, people don't build inverters to generate an output voltage, they aim to generate an output current of the correct phase. Result, most of the complication addressed in that 'tutorial' goes away, you can forget about the voltage across the output inductor filter. But, don't take my word for it. Try to design a voltage-output inverter, and a current-output inverter, and see which is simpler and more stable. The equations are more relevant if we replace the inverter with a real rotating power-station alternator.

@Neil_UK secondly there is a difference between the real and reactive current transfered. Which is in actual grid tied inverter used. If I werent to take the phases in consideration then I have to take the reactive power in consideration and transmit that

@kam1212 If you only have a generator, then yes, you have to do all that stuff. An inverter is not a generator, it has agile current output. If you program an inverter to be like a generator (slowly changing output voltage, slowly changing phase), then you have to do all that stuff. If you program your inverter more simply to deliver the current output that the hardware naturally wants to, all that complication falls away. I'm done with this discussion, I've taken your horse to clean water several times, but it's refused to drink, presumably preferring the muddy stuff it's used to.
